# Nested SELECT "works" when using nonexistant column - why?

Tags: sql, sqlite

folks, I have the following query in SQLite:

```sql
select license, username from check_table where
(
    username not in (
        select username from Address
    )
) order by license, username;
```

`Address` is another table. The fun part is: `Address` has no `username`column!!

Details:

- Result: `Query finished in 0.004 second(s)`
- If I modify the `username` part (e.g. to `userrname`) I get a `no such column` error, which is totally fine
- it never returns any results, even when I replace `username` with `mail_username` (which actually exists) in the sub-select - which is totally strange, because it really should.

Now, my question is: Why don't I get an error here?! And does it have something to do with the fact that I never get any results?

Comment: I can't imagine that this is actually reproducible.  What happens when you run `SELECT username FROM Address` on the command line?  Does that return anything or give an error?

Comment: This code works also in MySql, SQL Server, Postgresql etc. `username` is the column from `check_table`

Comment: `check_table` has the column and without explicitly telling the parser which table it should take for a column it searches from most local, here `address`, to most global, here `check_table`, and voilá, there is a column `username` found in `check_table`. To circumvent that explicitly qualify columns like `<table name or alias>.<column name>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're selecting `username` from the `check_table`, not from the `address` table.

Try to add aliases and check it out:

```
select ct.license, ct.username 
from check_table as ct
where
(
    ct.username not in (
        select ct.username 
        from Address as a
    )
) order by ct.license, ct.username;
```

I bet if you will try to use `select a.username...` you'll get an error about not existing column.

For this purpose, all the time when you're using multiple tables in the query is good to use aliases.

Comment: that's the thing :) . I had no idea about lookup rules in SQL. don't understand the use case, too - but I'm also a SQL noob ;) . Thanks!

Comment: the really annoying thing is - it still does not return any results. but when I do this: `select ct.username, a.mail_username from check_table as ct left join Address as a` I get a LOT of `NULL`s on the right side.